# jQuery: Need to change a particular list element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Currently I am working on Image Gallery app. 
It has `<img>` in `li` element.

Code as follows:

```js
var $slideR_wrap = $(".slideRoller_wrapper");
var $slidesRoller = $slideR_wrap.find(".slidesRoller");
var $slideRoller = $slidesRoller.find(".slideRoller");
var $sliderImage = $slideRoller.find(".rollerImage");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slideRoller_wrapper">
  <ul class="slidesRoller" id="slidesRoller">
    <li class="slideRoller">
      <img class="rollerImage" src="../../assets/img/slider/1.jpg">
    </li>
    <li class="slideRoller">
      <img class="rollerImage" src="../../assets/img/slider/2.jpg">
    </li>
    <li class="slideRoller">
      <img class="rollerImage" src="../../assets/img/slider/3.jpg">
    </li>
    <li class="slideRoller">
      <img class="rollerImage" src="../../assets/img/slider/4.jpg">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

How do I target a particular element of `li` as an array element?

When I did `console.log($sliderImage)`, I got an array of all the images.
And when I tried `$(".rollerImage")[0].css('opacity','1');`, it raised an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...)[0].css is not a function.

I need to access a particular `image` in particular `li` by using an array index.

This is the last step of my project and I really don't want to change the logic and start again.

Comment: `$(" li.slideRoller:nth-child(" + index + ") .rollerImage").css('opacity','1');`

Answer (score 0):

What you need is nth-child() selector.

Documentation : https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Examples : https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_nthchild.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can filter $elements array:

```
$(".rollerImage").filter(function(i, $el){return i===0}).css('opacity','1');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.slideRoller').eq( $index ).css('opacity','1')
```

$index is a position "li"

```
$('.slideRoller').eq( 0 ).css('opacity','1')
```

Comment: thanx.. I almost about about `$('.slideRoller').eq( 0 ).css('opacity','1')` Thanks a lot again..

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the list elements using `each()` function.

```
$("#slidesRoller").each()
var ele = [];
$('#slidesRoller').children('list').each(function () {
    ele.push(this);
});
console.log(ele); //This will be having the list of `List` tag.
console.log($(ele[0]).find("img")) // This will return the image in the first list.
$(ele[0]).find("img").css("opacity","0") // Set the opacity.
```